# Are there comprehensive parts lists available for vehicles?

Tags: parts, part-identification

I am looking for a particular part for my new '99 Dodge Ram 1500.  I have found that it is very difficult to locate OEM part numbers for individual items in the car.  My thought process is that if I can find the OEM part it makes it a lot easier to call around to see who might have the part available.  In my case, I'm looking for an interior trim retainer clip that is yellow nylon and appears to be called a "christmas tree retainer."  The service manual says `6506878aa` is the part number but searches for that don't seem to return any retainer clips.  After calling the dealer, they notified me that the part number is actually `6503709`.

Having a place where I can look up comprehensive parts lists for my vehicle, right down to the individual part numbers for bolts, would be really helpful.  I figure that auto parts stores have large databases for just this sort of thing; I'm wondering if there is anything I can use as a home user to try to find the proper part numbers for various components?

Comment: You can always call the dealership.

Comment: @Paulster2 I'd hate to have to keep calling the dealer for every little part I need to replace.  I was hoping there was an independently searchable resource somewhere that mechanics might know about that the lay-man wouldn't.

Comment: The easiest way I have found to find parts for any vehicle is to research it through RockAuto.com. They have the most complete list of parts available online for the best price I have been able to find. You wouldn't need the PN to find the part, and ultimately it will provide you with a PN, whether OEM or not.

Comment: According to the answer I got at [Determining the size/pitch of bolts and nuts before taking things apart](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/6531), "parts books" do exist. (Whether or not you can actually track one down is another matter.)

Answer (score 1):

See if there's a "Pull a part" close to you. It's the walmart of junkyards. They have computers that you just type in your car make and model and gives you a list of similar cars on the lot and they can manually look up other parts that are swappable.